# How to pass class instance as argument to member function in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to create class in lua and I need to pass as argument to member function instance of another class.

```
-- inside class definition

function Calculator:add( numberClassInstanceWithAdditionDataEncapsulated )
  return numberClassInstanceWithAdditionDataEncapsulated:value();
end


-- numberClassInstanceWithAdditionDataEncapsulated is instance of my custom class SNum 
-- which contains methods and data and other stuffs, it is not number from language.
-- it doesn't build when I change value to showMyNumber ( bothfunctions are members 
-- of SNum class)
```

I get error

```
attempt to index local 'numberClassInstanceWithAdditionDataEncapsulated' (a number value)
```

How to pass instance of another class to member function ?

Comment: The error says `numberClassInstanceWithAdditionDataEncapsulated` is is number, you can't call `:value` on it.

Comment: The mistake must be at the call site, which you haven't shown.

Comment: @YuHao It is not number, it is instance of my custom classandwhenI change value()yo anything other still get same error.

Comment: @TomBlodget This is class declaration, I didn't call anywhere in code yet because it shows error when I try to build project

Comment: Then you need to show us the code that calls `Calculator:add`, because clearly although you think the function call parameter should be an instance of SNum, in practice it is not, i.e. you have a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur only in runtime, and the error message is clear: numberClassInstanceWithAdditionDataEncapsulated is a number and can not be indexed. It is not a table ('objects' or class instances are usually tables) as you probably expected.